# obd2 device on obd1 vehicle?

Tags: chevrolet, obd, gps

is there any way to make a obd2 plug in device (example gps tracker Metro Smart Ride) work on a obd1 vehicle. The device works and still has service. I no longer own a vehicle with obd2, but I'd still like to be able to see where my truck is.

Comment: No there is not a way, they are completely different communication standards.

Answer (score 1):

This device seems like it is only using the power and ground provided by the obd2 to power itself. This is easy to mimic. If you wanted to be cheap you could just attach a wire with proper fitting terminal to pins 5 & 16  on your device and then ground the wire for pin 5 and find a constant battery supply for the wire attached to pin 16. If you wanted to be fancy you could cut a obd2 connector from a car in junk yard and wire a ground and B+.

Facing the pins on your device the pin out would be:

8--- -- ---1

16--------9

Facing a obd2 your pinout would be

1--- -- ---8

9--------16

Pin 5 = Ground ,Pin 16 = Battery +

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you can also just patch power in to the device from the fuse panel directly. This may let you put it in a more inconspicuous place if you are worried about theft at all.